# Convert array to SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swifty-json

I've got an NSArray of JSON objects converted by .rawString() saved on the NSUserDefaults.

Here is the print for the **lanesToReturn** NSArray:

```
(
"{\n  \"Sentido\" : 2,\n  \"DenominacaoTPTS\" : \"CH\U00c1CARA MARIA TRINDADE\",\n  \"Circular\" : true,\n  \"CodigoLinha\" : 34998,\n  \"Tipo\" : 10,\n  \"DenominacaoTSTP\" : \"TERM JD. BRIT\U00c2NIA\",\n  \"Informacoes\" : null,\n  \"Letreiro\" : \"1015\"\n}",
"{\n  \"Sentido\" : 1,\n  \"DenominacaoTPTS\" : \"CH\U00c1CARA MARIA TRINDADE\",\n  \"Circular\" : true,\n  \"CodigoLinha\" : 2230,\n  \"Tipo\" : 10,\n  \"DenominacaoTSTP\" : \"TERM JD. BRIT\U00c2NIA\",\n  \"Informacoes\" : null,\n  \"Letreiro\" : \"1015\"\n}",
"{\n  \"Sentido\" : 2,\n  \"DenominacaoTPTS\" : \"CENTER NORTE\",\n  \"Circular\" : false,\n  \"CodigoLinha\" : 33599,\n  \"Tipo\" : 10,\n  \"DenominacaoTSTP\" : \"CEMITERIO DO HORTO\",\n  \"Informacoes\" : null,\n  \"Letreiro\" : \"1016\"\n}"
)
```

Now, i need to convert this array back to JSON so i can display it.

My attempts so far:

1 - I was able to convert my Array to JSON but the keys inside don't work.

```
var jsonToReturn:JSON = JSON(lanesToReturn)
print(jsonToReturn[0])
print(jsonToReturn[0]["DenominacaoTSTP"].string)

**The result of the first print:**
{
  "Sentido" : 2,
  "DenominacaoTPTS" : "CHÁCARA MARIA TRINDADE",
  "Circular" : true,
  "CodigoLinha" : 34998,
  "Tipo" : 10,
  "DenominacaoTSTP" : "TERM JD. BRITÂNIA",
  "Informacoes" : null,
  "Letreiro" : "1015"
}

**The result of the second print:**
nil
```

2 - I've attempted to convert the array, but got the same results.

```
    do {

        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(lanesToReturn, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        var jsonToReturn:JSON = JSON(data:jsonData)
        print(jsonToReturn[0])
        print(jsonToReturn[0]["DenominacaoTSTP"].string)

    }catch let error as NSError{

        print(error.description)

    }
```

3 - Attempted to use JSON.parse() but got the same results

Can anyone can help me with that issue?

Comment: Side-note: Pretty print to save the JSON on disk is a pretty waste of space.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your first answer, did you try

```
jsonToReturn[0]["DenominacaoTSTP"].stringValue
```

?

Comment: Could you post more code about what "lanesToReturn" exactly is? And there is no reason to downvote

Comment: Yes i can, and it was not me who made the downvote, I'll vote up so it goes back to zero, I've got no reason to downvote somebody who is trying to help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Please edit your question with the code

Comment: I've updated the question with the lanesToReturn print!

Comment: could you post the exact line where you've declared lanesToPrint please?

Comment: let lanesToReturn:NSArray = NSArray.init(array: defaults.objectForKey("favLanes") as! NSArray)